# Парсинг приложения "оплати"

Tags: парсер, http, decode

Мне нужно написать парсер для приложения "Оплати" (https://www.o-plati.by/), он должен получать номер автобуса, исходя из заданной ссылки.
Пример ссылки: https://getapp.o-plati.by/map/?app_link=o-plati://o-transport/ticket/ysIFtqaHrerVzk1pa9vS9WpaqlY=&utm_medium=transport&ext_id=4002000153
У этого сервиса нету документации по api, поэтому я решил посмотреть куда отправляются запросы с приложения. Вот пример запроса, который я увидел:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: nginx 
Date: Sat, 30 Dec 2023 14:46:00 GMT 
bignsign: CAk0z9Sp8YA14BHWb45cuJOvWXp9wgB4h7cNeFNjWjWZSKy4mNX1RUk5U2R19VaV 
tkey: /Pzuu1g5Nk5XP4vHuMkMl8p8xUH5mFGvjfXC6Nq0dC1vDFnthHpFN85u4Zl9mvPdhM/xAjPa8w7h3IfRpimehEQcLPcJArXgnYbItmWpEbI= 
id: 1169268 
Content-Length: 4 
Content-Type: text/plain 
Content-Encoding: application/octet-stream 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: 0 
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
```

Поля content там не было, были лишь 2 эти зашифрованные строки. Как их можно расшифровать и получить с них какие-то данные?